# The screen flickered for a second, now files without an extension have a folder icon instead of the usual plain paper icon

Tags: macos, icon, monterey, file-extensions

For example, `touch Test` would normally create a `Test` file *without an extension* that should have the usual plain paper white icon. Now it's always set to a blue folder icon. The system "knows" it's not a folder since it's opening it in TextEdit and `Open with:` is set to TextEdit.

`touch Test` or `echo "test" > Test` both create files with the bad icon.

I also tried creating a new text file with **TextEdit**; kept the `Untitled.txt`, then *removed the extension* leaving only `Untitled`. **The icon jumped immediately to a folder icon.**

I tried many things from restarting the system to clearing the iconservices, and the iconcache. I also tried Killing the Dock and Finder, rebuilding the LaunchServices database, and restarting again. I just can't get the icon associated with files without extension to go back to the basic plain paper white one.

[image: Makefile]

Any idea on **how I can get the default plain paper white icon back?** Thx

**Complementary info:** The extension is not hidden with `Hide extension`, there's simply no extension like with Makefiles, etc.

```
mdls -name kMDItemContentType -name kMDItemContentTypeTree -name kMDItemKind Makefile

kMDItemContentType     = "public.make-source"
kMDItemContentTypeTree = (
    "public.make-source",
    "public.script",
    "public.source-code",
    "public.plain-text",
    "public.text",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content"
)
kMDItemKind            = "Makefile"
```

**System Info:** MacBook Pro M1, macOS Monterey 12.4

**More things I tried:**

- `qlmanage -r cache && qlmanage -r` followed by a `killall Finder` didn't help
- Disabled every QuickLook extension and reran the above command
- Stopped BlueHarvest to avoid .DS_Store files being removed
- Tried with a Guest User account
- Deleted ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.finder folder and restarted
- Ran the full list of OnyX Maintenance tasks (restart included)
- Restarted in Safe Mode but the problem persists even in safe mode.

**Update regarding the LaunchServices database:**

I had already tried running the full OnyX maintenance suite and repeated that with the LaunchServices database rebuilding but, as an extra precaution, I also reran the following  commands mentioned in several articles on eclecticlight.co and elsewhere with no results:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -v -all u,s,l`

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`

`sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -seed -lint -r -f -v -dump -domain local -domain system -domain user -domain network`

Followed by `killall Dock` and a restart but the problem persists.

Comment: I believe associated file icons come from the LaunchServices database.  This page may be of interest: https://eclecticlight.co/2017/08/11/launch-services-database-problems-correcting-and-rebuilding/

Answer (score 1):

What shows up when you select the erroneous icon and hit the space bar? Does it preview a folder icon?

If so, then perhaps you could try `qlmanage -r` in Terminal, which causes the QuickLook daemon to be restarted and reset. I've noticed that QuickLook, ostensibly for viewing previews, has some influence over icon presentation, as well.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. That was the first thing I did. I forgot to mention it: `qlmanage -r cache && qlmanage -r` followed by a `killall Finder` but it didn't help. QuickLook indeed previews a Folder icon while showing an `Open with TextEdit` in the upper righ corner. Very disturbing.

Comment: The only thing that gets the icon to change, beyond adding an extension, is a `chmod +x Untitled` which changes the icon to the dark exec one. But I'm not going to set every file to executable just to get rid of the folder icon.

Comment: I just tried with a Guest User account and the problem persists.

Comment: Is the QuickLook process even running? What does `ps aux | fgrep QuickLook` tell you? I see eight processes running, at least two of which have PIDs under 1,000, which means they were probably started as part of the boot sequence.

Comment: `ps aux | fgrep QuickLook` yields the same result on my machine.

Comment: Do you think Extended Attributes (xattr) could have any role in this behaviour?

Comment: What happens when you type `ls -la@`?

Comment: Extended attributes may be keeping the QuickLook plug from working, but it's hard to image EAs being wrong on every single folder.

Comment: Thank you for your perseverance. `ls -ale@` doesn't yield anything unusual. I get `com.apple.macl  936` and `com.apple.progress.fractionCompleted   11` `0: group:everyone deny delete`. That's on the ~/Desktop.

Comment: You might try looking for extended attributes in the various QuickLook folders. (/System/Library/QuickLook/, /Library/QuickLook/, ~/Library/QuickLook/)

Comment: Alas, nothing unusual.